# How can I get the values of my WordPress $wpdb query in Jquery?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

I have this function to grab the zip codes from WooCommerce

```
    public function validate_zipcode () {

    global $wpdb, $woocommerce;

    $sql = ' SELECT location_code FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix. 'woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ';
    $sql .= "WHERE location_code IS NOT NULL";

    $zones = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return $zones;

}

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_zipcode', array( &$this, 'validate_zipcode' ));
```

I would like to use Jquery to get the results but I am unable to, the error response is a bad request, what am I doing wrong?

```
  jQuery(".check-zip").click(function(){

        var zipCode = jQuery("#custom_zip").val();
        var zipArray = [];

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'validate_zipcode'
                },

                success: function(data) {
                  console.log( data );

                },

                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                    console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown  );
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where are you setting `ajaxurl`?

Comment: Hi thanks for checking this out, it's definitely not the ajaxurl, as I'm using it in multiple other places, also if I switch out the 'validate_zipcode' call for another one of my functions, I'm able to get a response, so I'm assuming it's something about the php function.  The php function works fine by itself by the way.

Comment: Is `validate_zipcode` in a class? You've hooked it like this `array( &$this, 'validate_zipcode' )` and have `public` there, but I can't see where `add_action` is used in relation to this.

Comment: Yes, validate_zipcode is in a class.  Someone has said that I need to create an api endpoint and call that endpoint from jquery.  I think this means using the "register_rest_field" function, but I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the WooCommerce api with only jQuery.

```
   $(".check-zip").on('click', function () {

      var zipCode = jQuery("#custom_zip").val();
      var zipArray = [];
      var url = WPURLS.template_url;

      $(".zip-msg").remove();

      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url + '/wp-json/wc/v2/shipping/zones/1/locations',

          dataType: "json",
          data: {
              type: 'postcode'
          },
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce);
          },

          success: function (data) {

              $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                  zipArray.push(value.code);

              }); //end each function


              if ($.inArray(zipCode, zipArray) > -1) {

                  $("#custom_zip_checkout_field").append("<div class='zip-msg'>Service is available at " + zipCode + "</div>");

              } else {
                  $("#custom_zip_checkout_field").append("<div class='zip-msg'>Oops! We are not currently servicing your area.</div>");
              }

          },

          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


              console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

          }


      }); //end ajax function

  });



                if($.inArray(zipCode, zipArray) > -1 ) {

                   jQuery("#custom_zip_checkout_field").append("<div class='zip-msg'>Service is available at " + zipCode + "</div>");

                   }else{
                          jQuery("#custom_zip_checkout_field").append("<div class='zip-msg'>Oops! We are not currently servicing your area.</div>");
                   }

                },

                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {


                    console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown  );

                }


            });//end ajax function

    });
```